# Installed Unity without hub version and now unity hub won't allow me to add module

Tags: unity-game-engine

i installed unity 2019.3.10f without unity hub. Now i want to download modules such as android , sdk ,ndk and jdk (recommended ones) but hub does not give option to add module.

[Unity version is latest same as hub but radio button is disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4WRa.jpg)

Comment: Usually the HUB only works well if Unity was installed via the HUB ... just uninstall Unity and reinstall it via the HUB

Comment: every time i try to install from hub. it disappears after sometime during installation.

Comment: you dont add modules like that.. you add them by clicking on the 3 dots next to the version you want to add modules to.. the add button only is for adding versions

Comment: the three dots only give 2 options 1) show in explorer 2) remove from hub. How do i add module?

Answer (score 2):

You can re-enable the option 'Add Modules':

```
Windows
1- go to C:\Users\{USER_NAME}\AppData\Roaming\UnityHub

MacOS
1- go to ~/Library/Application/Support/UnityHub

2- open editors.json file.
3- change "manual":true to "manual":false
4- kill the UnityHub and restart it. Note: Do not forget is stays in the tray on Windows.
```

Comment: Thank you, that actually worked for me. One more thing, I had to kill the process in the task manager.

Answer (score 1):

So, i searched and found out that if you don't download unity from unity hub you cannot add modules from unity hub.
I didn't expected that but that's how it works.
So, i had to uninstall the old one and then install via unity hub.
The three dot option show modules only if its downloaded via unity hub.
In short if you want unity hub's help you would have to play by unity hub's rules. That might be inconvenient to some extent.

Comment: I hope still this is true

Answer (score 1):

Here is [simple trick](https://askto.pro/question/why-isnt-unity-hub-opening-projects), and it worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The manual re-enable only seems to work if you have just one version of the editor installed. If you have more than one, it attempts to install the modules for the version you actually downloaded with the hub. This can break things. At this point, unfortunately, it seems you must uninstall the version that is not allowing modules to be added, and reinstall it directly through the hub.